# Python return statement not running

Tags: python

I am creating a program to figure out the highest number of decimals in a list of numbers. Basically, a list with `[123, 1233]` would return 4 because 1233 has four numbers in it and it is the largest. Another example would be that `[12, 4333, 5, 555555]` would return 6 because 555555 has 6 numbers.

Here is my code.

```
def place(listy):  
    if len(listy) == 1:  
        decimal = len(str(listy[0]))    
        print(decimal)  
    else:  
        if len(str(listy[0])) >= len(str(listy[1])):  
            new_list = listy[0:1]  
            for i in listy[2:]:  
                new_list.append(i)  
            place(new_list)  
        else:   
            place(listy[1:])
```

Now, when I use `print(decimal)` it works, but if I change `print(decimal)` to `return decimal`, it doesn't return anything. Why is this? How do I fix this? I have come across these return statements which doing run a lot of times. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that you seem to be mixing tabs and spaces in your source code. That is not good...

Comment: If you just call `place(listy)` with a return statement, it won't print. If you instead do `print place(listy)` it will print the returned value. Is this what you're doing? Your question seems a bit vague to me

Comment: What do you mean by "does not return anything"? Please provide the code where you call this function.

Comment: Just fyi, the code would be much simpler to use a list comprehension or generator expression like max(len(str(number)) for number in numbers)

Comment: Seeing your description, i see this can be simpler. `max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), listy))`

Comment: maybe I'll not answer your question, but a simpler way to do this could be `len(str(max(list_variable)))`

Comment: @javo, your one is better than my one :)

Comment: I don't want to have any print statements, if I run the function with [12, 4333, 5, 555555] has its input, it should compare 12 and 4333 then it should compare at 4333 and 5 and then it should compare 4333 and 555555 and see that 555555 has more numbers, so then it should look at 555555 and see that there is only 1 number left in the list. It does this, and then it should return 6 because there is 6 numbers in 555555. in the first if statement, it does print 6 when I use the print(decimal) statement. However, if I change it to 'return decimal' instead, it doesn't return anything. Why is that?

Comment: @user216485, why are you so insistent on doing it this way when there are other, simpler, clearer and faster ways proposed?  Is there a rationale behind your method?

Comment: @javo but what is list_ variable? I didn't initialize anything called list_variable right?

Comment: @jedwards No I was unaware that there is a simpler method.

Answer (score 9):

When you do a recursive call (i.e. when *place* calls *place*, and the called *place* returns a value, then the calling *place* must return it as well (i.e. the return value "bubbles up" to the initial caller).

So you need to replace every recursive call

```
place(...)
```

with

```
return place(...)
```

As others have said, there are easier solutions, such as using max(). If you want to keep a recursive approach, I would refactor your code as follows:

```
def place2(listy):
    if len(listy) < 1:
        return None
    elif len(listy) == 1:
        return len(str(listy[0]))
    else:
        v0, v1 = listy[0], listy[1]
        if v1 > v0:
            return place2(listy[1:])
        else:
            return place2([listy[0]]+listy[2:])
```

Although this is tail-recursive, Python does not really care so this approach will be inefficient. Using max(), or using a loop will be the better solution in Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the `return` doesn't do anything, it's that you don't propagate the return from your recursive call. You need a few more returns:

```
def place(listy):  
    if len(listy) == 1:  
        decimal = len(str(listy[0]))    
        return decimal
    else:  
        if len(str(listy[0])) >= len(str(listy[1])):  
            new_list = listy[0:1]  
            for i in listy[2:]:  
                new_list.append(i)  
            return place(new_list)  # <-- return added
        else:   
            return place(listy[1:]) # <-- return added
```

You can see the print at any level, but to get it back to the caller it needs to be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

The function does return the value, but it's not printing it out.
A simple way to solve this is, just call the function within a print statement. 

That is:

```
print(place(listy))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to find the maximum length of a list of integers, consider:

```
max([len(str(n)) for n in N])
```

For example

```
N = [1,22,333,4444]
max([len(str(n)) for n in N]) # Returns 4

N = [12, 4333, 5, 555555]
max([len(str(n)) for n in N]) # Returns 6
```

Note: This will only work for positive integers.

Or more simply:

```
len(str(max(N)))
```

Which will also only work for positive integers.

Answer (score -2):

Use ''global variable'' (google it) to access and change a variable defined outside of your function.

Comment: When someone arrives at this site, it should be the last stop before finding a solution. "Google it" is not helpful. Please, read [answer].