# Python return statement, frequent issue

Tags: python-3.x, return

The below program finds words like *code/cope/coje* etc. and returns the count of matches. However my return function is not giving me an output. `print(len(matches))` gives the right output but I need to use return. I see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895646/number-of-regex-matches) that '`findall`' is a more straightforward method, but I want to use finditer for now. Why isn't this return statement correct? I'm actually facing this problem in frequently as I write programs to learn python. I was unable to pick the answer from these references [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142863/return-statement-not-working-python-3),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577693/python-return-statement-not-running)

```
import re
mystr = "codexxxcmkkaicopemkmaskdmcone"

def count_code (char):
  pattern = re.compile (r'co\we')
  matches = pattern.finditer(char)
  result = tuple (matches)
  return len(result)

count_code(mystr)
```

`count_code (mystr)` didn't return anything, and did not return an error. See here : [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/QuirkySvelteDiskdrive)

Comment: Your `return` statement looks fine, but you're not actually calling the function anywhere.

Comment: "I was unable to pick the answer" .... picking things is not how you learn. By the way, is this your code? If you were able to define a function on your own, you should know the function needs to be called to run. Python does not have a "main" concept.

Comment: This code returns the number of matches found. We need more code to demonstrate the problem. You say, "print() works", in what way is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems to work fine. This is what I get when I run it in a local repl:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "codexxxcmkkaicopemkmaskdmcone"
>>>
>>> def count_code (char):
...   pattern = re.compile (r'co\we')
...   matches = pattern.finditer(char)
...   result = tuple (matches)
...   return len(result)
...
>>> count_code(mystr)
3
```

It isn't outputting anything in `repl.it` because you're not sending anything to output. Replace that last line with `print count_code(mystr)` and see the results:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>   
3
>
```

And here's my [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AbleExcitableClimate).

```
import re
mystr = "codexxxcmkkaicopemkmaskdmcone"

def count_code (mystr):

    pattern = re.compile (r'co\we')

    matches = pattern.finditer(mystr)
    matches = tuple (matches)

    return len(matches)


print count_code(mystr)
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding dumb. I ran the same program in Jupyter Notebook (with only return function) and it showed me an output. But the repl only shows an output with print. What is this? What do I have to know to understand the difference between how output is shown.